# What happened to Captain America's suit?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In ***The Winter Soldier***, **Captain America's** cool new suit seemingly disappears from the movie. He even breaks into the **Smithsonian** to steal his old suit so he has something to wear in the final battle.

***So what happened to his previous suit?***

Comment: Wouldn't his suit be in a locker in the SHIELD facility? I'm pretty sure he goes home without it - so he needs a suit and getting the old one from the Smithsonian would be easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When **Captain America** sheds his new stealth suit from **S.H.I.E.L.D.**, he does so because he believes it would be in bad taste to wear it whilst fighting HYDRA.

> After learning **HYDRA** has operated within **S.H.I.E.L.D.** for decades, Rogers sheds all ties to the organization and steals a modified version of the uniform he wore during World War II on display at The Smithsonian.

[**Source:**](https://geektyrant.com/news/the-evolution-of-captain-americas-uniform-ergt)

Comment: Anything official or canon to back it up? A blog post from a 3rd party isn't the most definitive source around.

Comment: My impression was that Rogers's intention was to use his WW2 suit to help Barnes recall him.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any reference to what happened to Cap's new suit in the final movie. But in the deleted scene it's shown that there's a tracking device in the suit that S.H.I.E.L.D. tries to use to hunt Cap down:

Even without this scene, I guess, we can still assume that Steve Rogers suspected something about the S.H.I.E.L.D. version of the suit and dropped it somewhere for a reason.